# Photoshop : Can I use modular elements?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a noob question (I guess).

I'm trying, with Photoshop CS6, **to make what I call modular elements for web layouts**.

I mean : when I make a header for a website, I would use the same source for all the layouts of this project. So I want to have a header.psd source in include it in every layout I will create for this project.

Then, if I need to modify the header, I just have to go in header.psd and modify it. The modifications will be effective on all the layouts which actually use header.psd as source.

*Pretty much the same as in web development : including file in another (e.g. with PHP).*

The thing is : smart objects don't do that (if I group some layers into a smart object, then modify this smart object, the modification will only be effective on the document where I created the smart object).

**Is it possible with PS CS6? how ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Photoshop CS6, No it is not possible.

In Photoshop CC, you can use `File > Place Linked` to **link** to an external file. When the external file changes, the existing Photoshop document link will update.